# How to use SatelliteResourceLanguages to filter out resource files when publishing .NET Core API services

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

When publishing .NET Core API services, the output includes with localized resources (cs, de, es, fr, etc.)

Searching for a solution to prevent .NET Core from publishing these localized resource files, I came across [this commit on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/2040) to implement `SatelliteResourceLanguages` for that purpose.

But how can I implement it?

Answer (score 26):

According to [this answer](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/6007#issuecomment-547041463), you should just add it to the project file:

```xml
<SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
```

Here's how you can use the above line in a project config:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en;de;pt</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FooBar" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Note that I couldn't find `SatelliteResourceLanguages` documented officially anywhere as of today.

Also note that you need to have a recent version of the SDK, as [this bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/3283) mentions that a typo prevented this to work properly in prior releases.

Comment: It's documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#satelliteresourcelanguages