# Language folders created for .NET Core application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 and created a C# `MSTest Test Project (.NET Core)` project. Every time the project is built, several 2-letter language folders are generated as per the image.

[image: Language folders automatically generated each build]

Each folder contains the files listed below:

- Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll
- Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.resources.dll
- Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.resources.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.resources.dll

These files and folders are unwanted. But if you delete them, they are re-generated on the next build.

Is there a way to switch them off?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294984/how-to-use-satelliteresourcelanguages-to-filter-out-resource-files-when-publishi

Comment: How are you certain that these folders are unwanted if you don't yet understand why they're being created?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a setting in the visual studio project properties but I managed to solve this problem by editing the csproj file directly.

Add SatelliteResourceLanguages to the primary property group like so...

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en-US</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you has been migrate your project

then maybe using "Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility"

see your csproj and delete this

Also, you can substitute 'Compatibility' to 'System.IO.Ports'

e.g System.IO...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).