How to block adding language resources for Microsoft.SqlServer.Types and Microsoft.ReportViewer in ASP.NET MVC project when it's compiling in VS 2022?
I have an ASP.NET MVC project with a report (Microsoft.ReportViewer). When I compile this project, VS2022 adds dll resources for various languages for Microsoft.SqlServer.Types and Microsoft.ReportViewer. But I need only the English versions.
I tried to find decision on a several resources and asked AI but the info found doesn't let to solve this problem.

Can you tell me where you saw the multiple language versions of the .dll resources that you mentioned? A screenshot would be very helpful.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294984/how-to-use-satelliteresourcelanguages-to-filter-out-resource-files-when-publishi/58595709#58595709
